# React Native - "fetch" from the Open Weather Api - Displaying information from an API

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

I'm having an issue with displaying this information from the Open Weather API. I used a fetch request to get the data and using the URL and my API_KEY, then I turn the response into JSON, and then I store the data in my state.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { styles2 } from '../../styles2';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

function Weather(props) {
    const  { name, key } = props;
    const [ weather, setWeather] = useState({});
    const [city, setCity] = useState('Lewisville');
    const API_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    const URL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${API_KEY}`;

    async function getWeather() {
      const data = await fetch(URL).then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log(data));
      setWeather({
        data: data
      });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      getWeather();
    })


    return (
        <View style={styles2.weatherContainer} >
        <View style={styles2.mainWeatherInfo}>
          <Text style={styles2.cityName}>{weather.name}</Text>
          <View style={styles2.tempInfo}>
            <Text style={styles2.mainTemp}>{((weather.main.temp - 273.15)*9)/5}°</Text>
          </View>
          <Text style={styles2.weatherDesc}>Light Rain</Text>
        </View>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Weather;
```

The API key is working, I am able to get the data and I can even see it in my terminal from the console.log. However, I can never display the information. `{weather.name}` doesn't display anything and `{weather.main.temp}` is always causing an error that says temp is undefined. I just need to know what mistake I'm making when using this API. I would appreciate any help.

Below is the data that is retrieved from the API:

```
Object {
  "base": "stations",
  "clouds": Object {
    "all": 98,
  },
  "cod": 200,
  "coord": Object {
    "lat": 33.0462,
    "lon": -96.9942,
  },
  "dt": 1622159817,
  "id": 4706057,
  "main": Object {
    "feels_like": 305.63,
    "humidity": 61,
    "pressure": 1007,
    "temp": 302.86,
    "temp_max": 303.56,
    "temp_min": 301.74,
  },
  "name": "Lewisville",
  "sys": Object {
    "country": "US",
    "id": 2009682,
    "sunrise": 1622114516,
    "sunset": 1622165326,
    "type": 2,
  },
  "timezone": -18000,
  "visibility": 10000,
  "weather": Array [
    Object {
      "description": "overcast clouds",
      "icon": "04d",
      "id": 804,
      "main": "Clouds",
    },
  ],
  "wind": Object {
    "deg": 235,
    "gust": 4.47,
    "speed": 0.89,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    async function getWeather() {
      const data = await fetch(URL).then(res => res.json());
      setWeather(data);
    }
```

1. You assigned `console.log()`(boolean false) as `data`.
2. If you set `setWeather({data: data})`, you should reference `weather.data.name`.

Comment: Yes, thats what I figured the first time when I tried {weather.data.name}, I get "Cannot read property of 'name' undefined.

Comment: I tried to get rid of the console.log and set the state as you did in your example and I am still getting the same error.